Bash child scripts - Timer interuptable by signals - read, timeout and sleep doesn't work
So, I'm on Arch Linux, running i3
I have a slideshow script that changes the background every 5 seconds. And I have a bunch of signals, such as toggle, next, previous, faster, slower. I have all of the signals scripts bound to a key.
And started/killing the slideshow is also bound to a key. In fact, I have a list of parrent scripts which does

Kill all other parrent scripts
Start the slideshow for this directory.

This allow me to start different slideshow using different keys.
I have a main loop and at the end of it, I want to place a "wait" $timer command before the loop reruns and go to the next one.
But I want this "wait" command to be interuptable by signals send from my other scripts.
Sleep isn't interupted, so unless i run in a loop sleep 0.00001s, which kills the point of signals, it won't react in real time when i press next or previous.
Timeout in terminal can execute, but inside a script, it can't even do the : command, it lacks permission.
read -t $timer worked perfectly when it was started from the terminal
, but the moment it's started from something else, it breaks.
I tried to do read from a subshell, read << /dev/null, none of it worked.
It's like if read, reads an empty set, rather then truly nothing.
I don't know how people mix signals with timers in scripts, but I'm sure it must be in the span of bash's capability.
I'd love any help.
Here's the code.
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Started Slideshow" -t 3000


timer=5 # seconds


# Function to change background using feh
change_background() {
    feh --bg-center --bg-fill --no-fehbg "$1"
}

# Default directory containing original images (if no path provided)
default_image_dir="Cool Pictures"

# Function to handle signals and manage natural cycling
signal_handler() {
    case $1 in
        "next")
            printf "Received next signal\n\n"
            next_image=true
            ;;
        "previous")
            printf "Received previous signal\n\n"
            prev_image=true
            ;;
        "toggle")
            notify-send 1
            if [ $slideshow_playing = true ] ; then
                slideshow_playing=false
            else
                slideshow_playing=true
            fi
            printf "Received toggle signal\n"
            printf "The slideshow is playing? $slideshow_playing \n\n"
            ;;

        "faster")
            printf "Recieved faster signal\n\n"
            timer=$(echo "$timer / 1.1" | bc -l)
            echo "new timer is $timer"
            ;;

        "slower")
            echo "Recieved slower signal"
            timer=$(echo "$timer * 1.1" | bc -l)
            echo "new timer is $timer"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown signal: $1"
            ;;
    esac
}


time_step=0.1
wait_until_timer() {
    local start_time=$(date +%s)
    local timer=$1
    local current_time
    local elapsed_time

    while true; do
        current_time=$(date +%s)
        elapsed_time=$((current_time - start_time))

        if [ $elapsed_time -ge $timer ]; then
            break
        fi

        sleep $time_step  # Adjust sleep duration as needed
    done
}


# Set up signal handlers
trap 'signal_handler "next"'     SIGRTMIN+1
trap 'signal_handler "previous"' SIGRTMIN+2
trap 'signal_handler "toggle"'   SIGRTMIN+3
trap 'signal_handler "faster"'   SIGRTMIN+4
trap 'signal_handler "slower"'   SIGRTMIN+5


# Arguments and directories setup
echo "arg 0: $0"
echo "arg 1: $1"
echo "arg 2: $2"
echo "arg 3: $3"

resized_dir=$2
true_dir="$HOME/Pictures/Desktop Background Slideshow/${1:-$default_image_dir}/$resized_dir"

# Initial setup or any other initialization logic can go here
printf "Reading from $true_dir \n\n"

# Shuffle images and store in an array
shuffle_images() {
    mapfile -d '' shuffled_images < <(find "$true_dir" -type f -print0 | shuf -z)
    total_images=${#shuffled_images[@]}
}

shuffle_images
i=0
slideshow_playing=true

# Main loop for natural cycling
while true; do
    if [ "$next_image" == true ]; then
        next_image=false
        single_play=true
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -ge $total_images ]; then
            i=0
        fi
    elif [ "$prev_image" == true ]; then
        printf "Previous image received, i=$i\n"
        prev_image=false
        single_play=true
        ((i--))
        if [ $i -lt 0 ]; then
            i=$((total_images - 1))
        fi
    elif [ $slideshow_playing = false ]; then
        #we pause here. double check to avoid indentation
        : # do nothing
    else
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -ge $total_images ]; then
            i=0
        fi
    fi

    if [ $slideshow_playing = true ] || [ $single_play = true ] ; then
        image="${shuffled_images[$i]}"

        if [ "$3" == "none" ]; then
            echo "Setting background to: $image"
        fi
        if ! [ -n "$2" ]; then
            printf "Changing to $image \n\n"
        fi
        change_background "$image"
        single_play=false
    fi 
    # Use read with timeout for natural cycling and signal interruption
    #wait_until_timer $timer
    wait $timer
done



Call sleep with the timeout duration, and store its PID somewhere. To interrupt, kill the process using the stored PID.

If I understand correctly, you have a main loop in your script and you want it to execute a task on a timer or when a signal is called.
This can indeed be done using read, but you need to connect it to a pipe.
Here is an example of how to do that with a FIFO:
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
shopt -s failglob

FIFO=test.FIFO  # can be changed to whatever

mkfifo "${FIFO}"         # create a fifo
trap 'rm "${FIFO}"' EXIT # clean fifo at end of script

trap 'echo > "${FIFO}"' SIGUSR1  # write to fifo: this will unblock read from fifo

while true
do
    echo hello!  # do stuff here


    # this will wait for either 1s or for someone to write to fifo
    read -t 1 <> "${FIFO}"  || true # remark:  <> "${FIFO}" => because any process connected to fifo cannot start until the fifo is opened for both read and write
done                                # remark2: || true      => because read will fail on timeout and I always use set -e in my scripts

UPDATE:
I found a simpler way to do this, but I am not completely sure it is as robust:
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
shopt -s failglob

trap 'kill $((pid)) || true' SIGUSR1  # kill sleep
# NOTE: I am not sure what happend if signaled during 'do stuff' or between 'sleep 1' and 'pid=$!'

while true
do
    echo hello! # do stuff here

    sleep 1 & # run sleep in the background so we can get its pid
    pid=$! # recover sleep pid
    wait $((pid)) || true # wait for sleep to stop or be killed
done



I tried it with fifio and it while it successfuly waits 5s when called as a child script, its not interupted by the next and previous signals. So I can't just press a button, and instantly switch picture. After the slideshow is stopped with toggle, when i execute next or previous signal, it can only change after the 5s timer, and multiple press don't stack.
reminder:
88 # Set up signal handlers
89 trap 'signal_handler "next"'     SIGRTMIN+1
90 trap 'signal_handler "previous"' SIGRTMIN+2
91 trap 'signal_handler "toggle"'   SIGRTMIN+3

oh, added signals to fifo in the switch and it works now

@Self learning student: yes. In fact, the trap 'echo > "${FIFO}"' SIGUSR1 that you kept is completely unnecessary in your script.
I like the functionality you implemented btw :-)

Let me start by adding a little bit for SEO if someone needs to google it.
How to create a slideshow script in i3 that changes background with feh. i3 window manager slideshow. Change background. Random slideshow. Next image using key press. Previous image using keypress. Pause slideshow feh. Archlinux slideshow script. Bash Linux script. Slideshow feh bash script.
Ok, should be good enough. Hope it helps whoever reads this more then the garbage ai generated stuff.

##################################################################

Here's the working code implementing user24246119's solution and adding a signal to fifo in the switch
slideshow.sh:
#!/bin/bash
notify-send "Started Slideshow" -t 3000


timer=5 # seconds


# Arguments and directories setup
echo "current script path: $0"
echo "Slideshow directory: $1"
echo "Resized option: $2"
echo "print option (Empty = print): $3"
echo "first image of slideshow: $4" # will be chosen randomly otherwise


# Default directory containing original images (if no path provided)
default_image_dir="Cool Pictures"
resized_dir="${2:-resized}"
true_dir="$HOME/Pictures/Desktop Background Slideshow/${1:-$default_image_dir}/$resized_dir"


# Check if $4 is provided and not empty; otherwise, choose a random image from $true_dir
if [ -n "$4" ]; then
    default_picture="$4"
else
    default_picture=$(find "$true_dir" -type f -print0 | shuf -n 1 -z)
fi

echo "default picture: $default_picture"



# Initial setup or any other initialization logic can go here
printf "Reading from $true_dir \n\n"



shopt -s failglob

FIFO=test.FIFO  # can be changed to whatever

mkfifo "${FIFO}"         # create a fifo
trap 'rm "${FIFO}"' EXIT # clean fifo at end of script



# Function to change background using feh
change_background() {
    feh --bg-center --bg-fill --no-fehbg "$1"
}


# Function to handle signals and manage natural cycling
signal_handler() {
    case $1 in
        "next")
            #notify-send "going to next picture"
            echo "next" > "${FIFO}"
            printf "Received next signal\n\n"
            next_image=true
            ;;
        "previous")
            #notify-send "going to previous picture"
            echo "previous" > "${FIFO}"
            printf "Received previous signal\n\n"
            prev_image=true
            ;;
        "toggle")
            if [ $slideshow_playing = true ] ; then
                notify-send "Stopped playing slideshow"
                slideshow_playing=false
            else
                notify-send "Restarted playing slideshow"
                slideshow_playing=true
            fi
            printf "Received toggle signal\n"
            printf "The slideshow is playing? $slideshow_playing \n\n"
            ;;

        "faster")
            printf "Recieved faster signal\n\n" -t 1000
            timer=$(echo "$timer / 1.1" | bc -l)
            notify-send "Faster | New timer is: $timer"
            ;;

        "slower")
            echo "Recieved slower signal"
            timer=$(echo "$timer * 1.1" | bc -l)
            notify-send "Slower | New timer is $timer" -t 1000
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown signal: $1"
            ;;
    esac
}




# Set up signal handlers
trap 'signal_handler "next"'     SIGRTMIN+1
trap 'signal_handler "previous"' SIGRTMIN+2
trap 'signal_handler "toggle"'   SIGRTMIN+3
trap 'signal_handler "faster"'   SIGRTMIN+4
trap 'signal_handler "slower"'   SIGRTMIN+5






shuffle_images() {
    local default_image="$1"  # Path to the default image

    # Find all images excluding the default image
    mapfile -d '' other_images < <(find "$true_dir" -type f ! -name "$(basename "$default_image")" -print0 | shuf -z)
    
    # Combine the default image with the shuffled images
    shuffled_images=("$default_image" "${other_images[@]}")
    total_images=${#shuffled_images[@]}
    
    printf "Inside shuffle: Default image= $default_image\n"
    printf "first image= ${shuffled_images[0]}\n"
    printf "second image= ${shuffled_images[1]}\n"
}





shuffle_images "$default_picture"
i=-1
slideshow_playing=true
next_image=false
prev_image=false
single_play=false

# Main loop for natural cycling
while true; do
    if [ "$next_image" == true ]; then
        next_image=false
        single_play=true
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -ge $total_images ]; then
            i=0
            shuffle_images "$default_picture"  # a function call
            notify-send "Reshuffled images"
        fi
    elif [ "$prev_image" == true ]; then
        printf "Previous image received, i=$i\n"
        prev_image=false
        single_play=true
        ((i--))
        if [ $i -lt 0 ]; then
            i=$((total_images - 1))
            shuffle_images "$default_picture"
            notify-send "Reshuffled images"
        fi
    elif [ $slideshow_playing = false ]; then
        #we pause here. double check to avoid indentation
        : # do nothing
    else
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -ge $total_images ]; then
            i=0
        fi
    fi

    if [ $slideshow_playing = true ] || [ $single_play = true ] ; then
        image="${shuffled_images[$i]}"

        if [ "$3" == "none" ]; then
            printf "Setting background to: $image\n\n"
        fi
        change_background "$image"
        single_play=false
    fi 
     # The timer part of the code
     read -t $timer <> "${FIFO}"  || true 
done


next.sh
#!/bin/bash
#notify-send "next" -t 3000

# Sending custom signal 1 to process named slideshow.sh
pkill -SIGRTMIN+1 slideshow.sh


previous.sh:
#!/bin/bash

pkill -SIGRTMIN+2 slideshow.sh

And you can probably see the pattern and apply it to the other 3 scripts.
Then you have stuff like i3:
bindsym $mod+Control+l  exec --no-startup-id $HOME/Pictures/Slideshow_Scripts/Master/next.sh

bindsym $mod+Control+j  exec --no-startup-id $HOME/Pictures/Slideshow_Scripts/Master/previous.sh


